# Bind HTML anchor tag to text block adaptive card

Tags: c#, html, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I want to add a HTML anchor tag to adaptive text block while showing the card. i'm using bot framework v3.0. Below is the code i'm using to add text block.

```
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
    Text = text with anchor tag,
    Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Default,
    Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Default,
    Wrap = true,
});
```

Please suggest....

Comment: Are you building a bot? What channel is the bot connected to? What purpose do you want this anchor tag to serve? Can you provide screenshots that explain your desired behavior?

Comment: sorry i want be able to provide a screenshot, but i can explain the behavior, i have build a TASK module in which i'm showing FAQ's. In answer of FAQ i want to show "See More"  title and in that i want to provide reference links.

Comment: Oh so you're saying you want to include hyperlinks in a text block? (In the future, please make sure you always say what channel you're using upfront.)

Comment: yes you are correct, so do you have any solution on this for hyper links in text block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Adaptive Card text supports a subset of Markdown.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features) You can use Markdown-style hyperlinks: `[Title](url)`

Answer (score 1):

Just fyi on Kyle's answer - the link must **exactly** follow the markdown syntax. As an example:

```
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
    Text = "[The Text for the link](https://thelink.goeshere.com)",
    Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Default,
    Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Default,
    Wrap = true,
});
```